# Firebase Functions Schedule Set by User

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm giving my users an option of "what day of the week would you like ..."
The user chooses a day of the week and I'd like a Firebase Function to fire once per week on the user's chosen day.

It seems I cannot, however, input any variable data into the Firebase Function Schedule feature.

I can run...

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {
    console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!'); 
});
```

But I can't seem to have the 'every 5 minutes' as a variable.

I can make a function fire once per week, but can I let the user decide what day it should fire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't vary the frequency of a scheduled function.  It must be set at the time it's deployed.  What you will have to do in your function is check to see which user-specified jobs should be run at the time the function is triggered, and only perform the ones that should be run.  So, this is not a matter of configuration - you will have to write the code to make this happen.

Comment: Yes. This is what i've discovered after many, many hours...  The way I made it work was have user put a date and time into the firestore, then have a task runner in the server checking every minute if now > user date and time.  If so, fire function and reset user date with + 7 days.  Found the solution here => https://fireship.io/lessons/cloud-functions-scheduled-time-trigger/ . (I'm not affiliated with the attached website in anyway)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple if you think outside the box.
Have the pubsub scheduled function run every minute (or every day) and inside the function use a condition (like context variable) to decide whether the user chose the current time to perform the event and your scheduled function will run if the times match only.